# Invalid Input Syntax for Type Double Precision in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have this query that is trying to update my geom column that's built off of lat and lng coordinates

```
UPDATE main_table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat) ,4326);
```

However it returns that `function st_makepoint(text, text) does not exist` and gives me a hint to add explicit type casts, so I updated my query to

```
UPDATE main_table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(
ST_MakePoint(lng:: double precision, lat:: double precision) ,4326);
```

And now it's throwing an error `invalid input syntax for type double precision:`.

Just a note, right now my lats and longs are stored as text because I had to use a `pg restore` to load the table, so I'm sure that's where the problem is but don't know how to address it.

Comment: you might have left out part of the error message; was it `invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""`? If so, you need to filter these out with `WHERE lng <> '' AND lat <> ''`.

Answer (score 3):

No space should be (also float8 is the same as double precision and a bit faster to type)

```
UPDATE main_table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(
  ST_MakePoint(lng::float8, lat::float8) ,4326);
```